# robot test framework: Run Keyword If incurs User keyword contains no keyword

Tags: robotframework

The following codes are in a For Loop.

`ELSE    Enable Laser    ${app_id}    ${status}` incurs **User keyword 'Enable Laser' contains no keyword** error. However, if I change it to `ELSE IF   '${electricalApp}'=='True'    Enable Laser    ${app_id}    ${status}`, then no error on this line, but the line `Run Keyword If    '${electricalApp}'=='True'    Enable Laser    ${app_id}    ${status}` right below, incurs **User keyword 'Enable Laser' contains no keyword** error.

```
\   ${electricalApp}    Is App Electrical    ${app}
\   ${status}    Set Variable    ON
\   ${validOptic}    Set Variable    False
\   ${validOptic}    Run Keyword If    '${electricalApp}'=='False'    Is Optic Valid For App    ${app_id}    ${app}
\   ...              ELSE    Enable Laser    ${app_id}    ${status}
\   Run Keyword If    '${validOptic}'=='True'    Enable Laser    ${app_id}    ${status}
\   ${status}    Set Variable    OFF
\   Run Keyword If    '${electricalApp}'=='True'    Enable Laser    ${app_id}    ${status}
\   Run Keyword If    '${validOptic}'=='True'    Enable Laser    ${app_id}    ${status}
\   Exit Current Running Apps
```

Before I put above code to For loop, everything works well.

EDIT: Enable Laser:

```
Enable Laser    [Arguments]     ${app_id}   ${status}
[Documentation]     Turn on or off laser and then check Signal Sync Link. ${status} should be all upper case
    ${commmand}    Catenate    SEPARATOR=    ${app_id}    .0.SignalTx.LaserEnable
    send cmd    ${app_id}    a_goto_state    ${commmand}    ${status}
    ${inquiry}    Catenate    SEPARATOR=    ${app_id}    .0.SignalTx.LaserState
    ${payload}    send cmd    ${app_id}    r_get    ${inquiry}
    ${parameters}    Evaluate    $payload.parameters
    Run Keyword If    '${status}'=='ON'    Should Be Equal    '1'    ${parameters}    Current state should be 1
    Run Keyword If    '${status}'=='OFF'    Should Be Equal    '0'    ${parameters}    Current state should be 0
    Signal Sync Link Verification    ${app_id}    ${status}
```

Comment: Could you please share with us code of that keyword `Enable Laser`?

Comment: @JanKovarik thanks, code been added.

Comment: please fix the formatting of the code. The first block is jumbled up, with code intermixed with text.

Comment: @BryanOakley if you read it, you'll find those codes are part of text.

Comment: Please read and follow the advice here: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that in the definition of `Enable Laser`, the `[Documentation]` needs to be indented.

like this:

```
Enable Laser    [Arguments]     ${app_id}   ${status}
    [Documentation]     Turn on or off laser and then check Signal Sync Link. ${status} should be all upper case
    ${commmand}    Catenate    SEPARATOR=    ${app_id}    .0.SignalTx.LaserEnable
    send cmd    ${app_id}    a_goto_state    ${commmand}    ${status}
```

Comment: That's crazy. I didn't notice and didn't try to copy paste. Anyway I'm glad you solved the problem.

Comment: Thank you much anyway. Indeed crazy, this shit held me for almost 1 day.